# How to view corresponding SQL query of the Django ORM's queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Is there a way I can print the query the Django ORM is generating?

Say I execute the following statement: `Model.objects.filter(name='test')`

How do I get to see the generated SQL query?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Each QuerySet object has a `query` attribute that you can log or print to stdout for debugging purposes.

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(name='test')
print(qs.query)
```

Note that in pdb, using `p qs.query` will not work as desired, but `print(qs.query)` will.

If that doesn't work, for old Django versions, try:

```
print str(qs.query)
```

**Edit**

I've also used custom template tags (as outlined in [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/159/)) to inject the queries in the scope of a single request as HTML comments.

Comment: what about queries for .save()?

Comment: @DataGreed Good question, might be worth asking in a new thread so you get more responses.

Comment: Does it work with `prefetch_related` i.e. show 2 queries? I see only 1.

Comment: doesnt work. i see `<django.db.models.sql.query.Query object`

Comment: Try print(str(qs.query)). I think they've changed the internals a bit in 10 years

Comment: What about `Model.objects.create`? I'd really like to see the SQL for that too.

Comment: @JoeHolloway you saved the day with your comment on `print(str(qs.query))`. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: !!! Be sure to have DEBUG=True .  I just wasted a whole lot of time just due to this

Comment: @Hammad this answer shouldn't require DEBUG=True whereas some of the other answers that inspect `connection.queries` do need it. However, if you want to log queries from production, it's probably better to use DB logging or a configurable Python logger than a solution requiring DEBUG=True anyway.

Comment: Also in pdb, just `str(qs.query)` works very simply

Answer (score 128):

You also can use python logging to log all queries generated by Django. Just add this to your settings file.

```
LOGGING = {
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            # logging handler that outputs log messages to terminal
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG', # message level to be written to console
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            # this sets root level logger to log debug and higher level
            # logs to console. All other loggers inherit settings from
            # root level logger.
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False, # this tells logger to send logging message
                                # to its parent (will send if set to True)
        },
        'django.db': {
            # django also has database level logging
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
    },
}
```

Another method in case application is generating html output - [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) can be used.

Comment: If somebody would like to have **summary with sumup** of **number of executed queries** as well **total time** it took: http://www.dabapps.com/blog/logging-sql-queries-django-13/

Comment: It did not work for me, I had to add `'level': 'DEBUG'` under `'django.db'`.

Answer (score 117):

You can paste this code on your Django shell which will display all the SQL queries:

```
import logging
l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Answer (score 80):

As long as `DEBUG` is on:

```
from django.db import connection
print(connection.queries)
```

For an individual query, you can do:

```
print(Model.objects.filter(name='test').query)
```

Answer (score 29):

Maybe you should take a look at `django-debug-toolbar` application, it will log all queries for you, display profiling information for them and much more.

Comment: This is very useful, but it only works in the GUI and sometimes you want to see query logs directly in ORM.  e.g. you have an api , with no GUI!

Answer (score 2):

A robust solution would be to have your database server log to a file and then

```
tail -f /path/to/the/log/file.log
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using database routing, you probably have more than one database connection. 
Code like this lets you see connections in a session.
You can reset the stats the same way as with a single connection: `reset_queries()`

```
from django.db import connections,connection,reset_queries
...
reset_queries()  # resets data collection, call whenever it makes sense
```

...

```
def query_all():
    for c in connections.all():
        print(f"Queries per connection: Database: {c.settings_dict['NAME']} {c.queries}")

# and if you just want to count the number of queries
def query_count_all()->int:
    return sum(len(c.queries) for c in connections.all() )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Django debug_toolbar to view the SQL query. 
Step by step guide for debug_toolbar usage :

#### Install the Debug_toolbar

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

#### Edit settings.py file & add debug_toolbar to Installed apps, this should be added below to 'django.contrib.staticfiles'. Also add debug_toolbar to Middleware.

Settings.py=>

```
INSTALLED_APPS= [ 'debug_toolbar'] 

MIDDLEWARE = ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']
```

#### create a new list named INTERNAL_IPS in settings.py file

Settings.py=> create new list at the end of settings.py file & add below list:

```
INTERNAL_IPS= [127.0.0.1']
```

This will allow the debug to run only on internal developement server

#### Edit urls.py file of #Project & add below code:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))       
    ] + urlpatterns
```

#### apply migrate & run server again

You will see an add-on on your web page at 127.0.0.1 & if you click on SQL Query check box, you can actually see the run time of query as well.