# optimizing this django code?

Tags: python, django

I'm having some performance issues because I'm making a lot of query calls that I'm not sure how to reduce.

user_item_rel_set is a m2m relation between user and items showing how much a user paid for a particular item.  Each item can have multiple users and buyers, and I'm trying to get the m2m relation for a particular user.

```
        # find anything that you bought or used and how much you paid for it
        u = User.objects.get(id=self.uid)
        t = self.list.filter(user_item_rel__user__exact=u)
        y = self.list.filter(buyer_item_rel__buyer__exact=u)

        items = t | y 
        items = items.distinct()
        u = User.objects.get(id=self.uid)
        for t in items:
            try: 
                t.price = t.user_item_rel_set.get(user=u).payment_amount
            except:
                t.price = -1 * t.buyer_item_rel_set.get(buyer=u).payment_amount
        return items
```

and at another instance

```
    for i in new_list:
        if str(i.tag) not in x:
            x[str(i.tag)] = 0 

        if houseMode == 0:
            x[str(i.tag)] += float(i.user_item_rel_set.get(user__id__exact=self.uid).payment_amount)
        else:
            x[str(i.tag)] += float(i.price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some additional code from your model would help, because it's hard to see what the 'items' queryset contains.

I will try to help anyway...

Because you've modeled a relationship between users and items, there is no need to iterate over every item in that queryset when you can simply select the subset that are interesting to you.

Again, I'm having a bit of difficulty following your application logic, but I think your queries can be reduced to something of this nature:

```
# Find all the items where this user is the "user"
user_items = items.filter(user_item_rel_set__user=u)

# Find all the items where this user is the "buyer"
buyer_items = items.filter(user_item_rel_set__buyer=u)
```

I don't quite follow why you are assigning these values to 't.price' in the loop or I would expand on that code.

If that doesn't help your performance, I recommend [dumping your SQL queries to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971667/django-orm-how-to-view-or-log-the-executed-query) so you can see exactly what's going on behind the ORM.  In logic like this, it shouldn't take more than a handful of SQL statements to arrive at your calculation.

Furthermore, it is generally a bad idea to use floating point datatypes (float) anywhere in proximity to a monetary value.  Floating point datatypes are generally for scientific applications where performance is more important than precision.  If you're dealing with money, precision is almost always more important than performance, so you use a datatype capable of exact representation like decimal.Decimal *everywhere*.

**Edit**

Given the comments, I recommend starting your query with the "relationship" object instead of the Item.  Since your sample doesn't tell me the name of that class, I will assume it's called UserItem:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from decimal import Decimal

price = Decimal('0')

# Get all UserItems where this user is the user or buyer
interesting_items = UserItem.objects.filter((Q(user=u) | Q(buyer=u)))
for ii in interesting_items:
    if ii.user == u:
        price += ii.payment_amount
    elif ii.buyer == u:
        price -= ii.payment_amount
    else:
        assert False, "Oops, this shouldn't happen"

# Do something with 'price'...
```

The Django "Q" facility lets you get a little more granular with your queries.  If you need to filter based on some attribute of the item, throw that in there too.

The part that still confuses me in your examples, is why are you assigning 'price' to the item object when it is clear that many users will share that item.

**Edit 2**

You can also use the [aggregation API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses) to let the DBMS compute the sum if that's all you're interested in:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
buyer_price = UserItem.objects.filter(item=i, user=u).aggregate(
                 Sum('payment_amount'))['payment_amount__sum']
```

Comment: So Item has a price, and its m2m relationship (user_item_rel) has how much a user paid for that item.  I have a list of items the user is involved in (exactly the code you have), and I'm trying to retrieve how much the user paid for each item, though I can't do this without hammering the database for every single item.

Comment: So the 'payment_amount' field is stored on the relationship object between a user and item?  I assume that m2m relationship has its own model?

Comment: Even my latter example is still missing something, but I can't say what from the details you've given.  Perhaps you just need a map of items to price from there, which would be pretty simple.  

Maybe if you described what inputs you have and what outputs you expect, it would be easier to provide help?

Comment: Sure. So let's say I have a list of items: cheese $4, bread 5$, milk 4$.  I pay $3, $3, and 2$, and the rest is paid for by person B.  The Item model for cheese is: name-cheese, price 4. The m2m for me is item=cheese, user=me, payment=$2. Same for Person B, for all the items.  Now I'm given a list of those items, and I want to get how much I paid for each.  So given the code above, I look at each item (let's say i) and do i.user_item_rel_set.get(user=me). That gives me $2. And then I do it for the rest.  Does this clear things up?