# django select max field from mysql when column is varchar

Tags: python, django, mysql, max, varchar

Using Django 1.1, I am trying to select the maximum value from a varchar column (in MySQL.)  The data stored in the column looks like:

9001
9002
9017
9624
10104
11823

(In reality, the numbers are much bigger than this.)

This worked until the numbers incremented above 10000:

```
Feedback.objects.filter(est__pk=est_id).aggregate(sid=Max('sid'))
```

Now, that same line would return 9624 instead of 11823.

I'm able to run a query directly in the DB that gives me what I need, but I can't figure out the best way to do this in Django.  The query would be:

```
select max(sid+0) from Feedback;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of "any help would be much appreciated", you should figure out why it stopped working inside Django (but apparently not inside MySQL) - at 10,000.

What is the query that is being generated? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971667/django-orm-how-to-view-or-log-the-executed-query) for how to find that out.

I suspect it is because you're adding the +0 to make the sort numeric in your query. I don't think Django supports this naturally, so you have two options:

- People will undoubtedly want to know why you're storing a number and asking for the maximum of it in a VARCHAR column. You could change the column to a [numeric data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html).
- You could do what you have to do whenever you want to make some custom SQL call and Django doesn't *yet* support it: [write your own raw SQL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql).
- Edit: You could also patch Django, but this might be a MySQL specific thing, so option #2 is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.


The +0 is something that I tried directly in MySQL after I saw the problem.  It is not part of the original query.  The original query run in MySQL also returns the wrong result.

The reason the number is stored in a VARCHAR is because there are other rows that have non-numeric values for that column.  I'm working with a subset of that data which does happen to return all numeric values (stored as varchar.)

I took your advice and dropped into raw SQL.  Works like a charm.

Thanks!