# How to print mysql statements executed / to be executed on a statement in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want want to examine what django does with databse when I execute some statement with a django model
For instance

```
Group.members.all()
```

with manage.py shell.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django orm, how to view (or log) the executed query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971667/django-orm-how-to-view-or-log-the-executed-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print Group.members.all().query
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Django Debug Toolbar.

- [Introducing the Django Debug Toolbar](http://rob.cogit8.org/blog/2008/Sep/19/introducing-django-debug-toolbar/)
- [django-debug-toolbar (github)](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: +1. And for the shell, the debug toolbar adds an extra manage.py command - `debugsqlshell` that prints the SQL for every ORM command you type.