# Django + postgresql: log how long a query took to execute?

Tags: django, postgresql

Beginner question, and it's probably a duplicate, sorry! But I can't find the answer by Googling or by searching on here.

My Django/postgres application is slow. I know how to log the [queries being executed on postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971667/django-orm-how-to-view-or-log-the-executed-query), so I'm doing that.

Now, how do I identify which of them are slow... short of typing them all in myself, and using a stopwatch?

In short: is there a way to log how long each query took to execute, using Django ORM & a postgres database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). Thanks me later.

Or if you want to do it manually then:

```
import time

start = time.time()
# execute your query here
stop = time.time() - start
print stop # or log this time
```

Answer (score 1):

log all slow queries

set log_min_duration_statement = 200ms in postgresql.conf file

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used pgFouine to analyse my postgres logs - see http://pgfouine.projects.pgfoundry.org/tutorial.html for how to set up logging and how to analyse them with pgFouine.