# Check query Django generates

Tags: django, django-orm

How can I check, which query django 1.4.11 generates for this query:

```
obj = Model.objects.get(code='code')
```

I've tried:

```
print Model.objects.get(code='code').query
```

but there is such method for model object.
How can I get  raw sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `query` is a property of the `Queryset` object and when you do a `.get()` the Queryset it´s evaluated (and became an instance of Model)

If you try:

```
>>> type(Model.objects.get(code='code'))
<class 'app.models.Model'>
>>> print Model.objects.get(code='code').query
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'query'
```

But instead with:

```
>>> type(Model.objects.all())
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
>>> print Model.objects.all().query
SELECT "model.Model" from ...
```

Now, to get the SQL of all the queries you have several options:

- If `DEBUG=True` you can use this:

  ```
  from django.db import connection
  print connection.queries
  ```
- Use django-debug-toolbar
- Use the built-in django logging https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-db-backends You can find examples on how to setup [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11373691/263989).