# How can I reverse a SQL Query to reach its Django source?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

Is it possible to reverse a complex sql query (consisting of joins and group by) to reach its Django source?

By source, I mean the model that might have triggered the query?

For example, consider the models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

A query that uses group by and left outer join on these models is fired. Can I trace it back?

Comment: Why don't you share the query with us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971667/django-orm-how-to-view-or-log-the-executed-query)

Comment: Do you know about the django debug toolbar: https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3/  It displays all the queries that execute for a request

Comment: @Wtower cant share the query as it is related to work, but I now have a fair idea of how to debug Django queries. Thank you Vaulstein for the redirect, but my question is in the reverse direction - I have a query and I need to know which models were involved when that query was triggered. Thank you, Joel Goldstick. Will check it out. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

May be this is the answer you are looking for.

Actually what i got from your comment 'I have a query and I need to know which models were involved when that query was triggered', you want to trace the models/tables which is getting involved in your query.

So for that you can use .query over your object.E.g;

```
exm = Example.objects.all()

print exm.query # This will give you the query which will be triggered in the back-end.
```

You can debug from your code or you can use **django-debug-toolbar**.